# What is the meaning of death?

Tags: death

I would want what is the meaning of death. Some people have different opinions:

- Death is an enfeeble form of life.
- Death is a continuation of life.
- Death is perpetual development.
- Death is waiting.

Comment: Could you please specify a bit the background of your question? Do you ask from a biological, religious, existential etc. context?

Comment: @JoWehler existential

Comment: The meaning of death is obviously; -42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an existential point of view: Death is the knowledge that our life will end.

After some time it will be for the generations then living, as if we had never existed. And after 5 billion of years, when the sun expires, all life on earth and all memory and documentation will vanish as if it did never exist.